Salesforce for Vlocode not connecting to a Salesforce Org in VS Code
I am trying to connect a Salesforce org to Vlocode to work/deploy Vlocity components via vs code.
But whenever I try to connect to a Salesforce Org, it shows up the below error
[SalesforceConnection] [error] GET https://my-domainname--dev1.sandbox.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v51.0/query?q=Select%20omnistudio__Value__c%20from%20omnistudio__GeneralSettings__c%20where%20Name%20%3D%20'VBTRequiredVersion'


At first I thought it's bcoz of not enabling Omnistudio Metadata settings... But tried with a developer org and enabled the OS Metadata settings and still the error occur
